# MySQL After Update trigger for different tables

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger which updates the overall user score after a user finishes a mission. I have two different tables, 'missions' and 'users'. After missions table is updated I want to send the score acquired to the users table and update the users.score for a respective user. I have mid, scoreacquired, and user_uid in missions table, and uid, score in users table. This is what I have so far:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS updateScore;
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER updateScore 
AFTER UPDATE ON missions
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE users SET score = score + missions.scoreacquired 
   WHERE users.uid = missions.user_uid;
END;
|
delimiter;
```

It allows me to create the trigger but when I trigger it, it gives me an error in the two lines after BEGIN. Any suggestions?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect to see `new` somewhere along the way.  Something like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS updateScore;
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER updateScore 
AFTER UPDATE ON missions
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE users
       SET score = score + new.scoreacquired 
       WHERE users.uid = new.user_uid;
END;
|
delimiter;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now it is complaining in syntax with delimiter at line 1. I am using MySQL if this is relevant. Thank you again.

Comment: If your original syntax worked, this should also work.

Comment: It worked. It does not accept it when I copy and paste from the browser but it worked when I typed it manually. Thank you.